# ISO image on hard drive?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, iso-image

All instructions I see state "flash drive or DVD"; what about an internal hard drive (e.g. D-drive)? I see D:\ as a "bootable device" in BIOS, so couldn't it install on a formatted C drive from there?

If "yes" - can the ISO image (of an existing C drive, i.e. backup) be burned directly onto the hard drive? The [installation media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) only offers the "ISO file - You'll need to burn the ISO file to a DVD later" option (or USB).

Comment: Are you trying to get a bootable Windows 10 DVD or USB stick? Your question is a bit confused so that it is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Robert I seek to make an ISO image of my current C-drive and restore it to a fresh (replacement) SSD, rather than install Windows from scratch. Did it before, but with a flash drive, but now C is too big.

Comment: ISO images are for CD/DVD not for backups. The link you have include dis for burning a DVD that allows you to install a fresh Windows 10 system. Use a regular image-based backup program like [Macrium](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree). Or if both drives are installed in the same PC you can simply clone the data from one drive to the second.

Comment: @Robert Right, I may be confusing terminology here - I'll give that a go, thanks.